# GIF rendering when run locally but does not render in deployment on cyclic.sh

Tags: html, deployment, web-development-server, cyclic

I want to send a static HTML error page when a user tries to reload the callback route of Spotify's OAuth flow. I use Nodejs for my backend and send the static HTML file using `res.sendFile()`. There is a GIF in the html which is visible when run locally but does not get rendered in the deployment. The site is deployed on cyclic.sh. The code of the HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spotube</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="error-container">
        <img src="totoro.gif" alt="Error image" class="error-image">
        <h3>Do not refresh this page or you'll have to go back and login again </h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()` pops up in the Chrome Developer Console but when I look at the Deployment Logs in Cyclic, I find these

[image: Cyclic Logs showing that the GIF was sent]

The files are also stored at the same level so I can't understand where I'm going wrong [image: File organization in my repo]

The result I want (which I get locally)
[image: The result I want (which I get locally)]

The result I get in my deployment
[image: The result I get in my deployment]

Comment: Can you navigate the the image directly? Right click on the broken image and select "open in a new tab" or something like that.

Comment: The server sends this JSON when I try to open image in a new tab
{
"message": "Internal Server Error"
}

Comment: Well, that at least narrows it down. If you know the path to the image is correct then there's nothing wrong with your HTML. Given the information you have shown so far I don't know how to direct you here. I'd suggest making a new question that simply mentions your server is showing that error message when you expect it to be an image instead.

Comment: Okay thank you, will do that